# Can I call a second instance oft the tinyMCE-editor within a tinyMCE-dialog?

Tags: tinymce

I have a textarea witch I can edit with tinimce.
I created a plugin witch saves or splits the Text into different strings (containing Text in different Languages separated by some special-tags within the title tag. It looks like :

Title=“|tag-d| some german text |tag-e| some english text |tag-f| some french text ...

These texts can be edited by the user in a Tinymce-dialog  (**this works fine!**)

```
   editor.windowManager.open({
      title: "Info",
      defaults: {type: 'textbox', multiline: 'true', minWidth:600, minHeight:100},
      body: [
      {name: 'deutsch', label: 'deutsch', value: deutsch},
      {name: 'franzoesisch', label: 'französisch', value: franzoesisch},
      {name: 'englisch', label: 'englisch', value: englisch},
      {name: 'italienisch', label: 'italienisch', value: italienisch},              
      ],
```

Now what I want to do is editing these Texts with another tinymce-instance so the user can format and specially add some links to the selected text  of each language. How do I call tinymce for the different textboxes under consideration of the words the user has selected?
Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

This seems possible.
All you will have to do is to write the text you would edit in a Tinymce-dialog into a textarea on your page and then init a tinymce for this textarea.
This new editor would open and you would need to write the contens back when the user is done (on button click).

Comment: Do you have some example-code how to write back to my page without closing tiny and getting the values back?
As I understood I have to Open Tiny on the primary textarea. (works) - 
Then select the text to edit. (works) - 
In the first dialog I split the content into the different languages (tinymce-textboxes) and show them to edit in. (works) - 
Then I write the textboxes back to my page (to the Textareas) leaving Tiny-dialog open (how?) - 
Then I start the new instance of Tiny for the selected languagetext (Textarea) (how?) - 
Edit this and writing it back to the first open dialog (how?)